# How to fix Exception with queryStringParameters?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to read GET request parameters:

I have an exception if there are no parameters.

```
event = objectMapper.readTree(input);
JsonNode queryParameterMap = event.findValue("queryStringParameters");
```

However, I have no exception if I use "queryParameters" instead of "queryStringParameters".

How could I **return null with no exception** if there are no parameters?

```
final String keyParameter = Optional.ofNullable(queryParameterMap)
                .map(mapNode -> mapNode.get("my_key").asText())
                .orElse(null);
```

It looks like Exception came from mapping stage.

Comment: Can you paste the whole code you are using and the exception you get?

Comment: @NeoChiri I have added a code where exception come from. I can't find what is return of queryParameterMap when there are no request parameters. That's a source of my question.

Comment: But you must have the stack trace of the Exception if you say it is returning an Exception. So in order to assist you, it would be helpful to have the Exception trace thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution.
I `just added Empty filter` and everything works now.

```
final String keyParameter = Optional.ofNullable(queryParameterMap)
                .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                .map(mapNode -> mapNode.get("my_key").asText())
                .orElse(null);
```